# JavaScript adding suffix to today's date

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get this code to work to have both the date and time and also output the suffix on the date, like July '3rd'. I have been trying to get the main date function try to call the suffix function, but I keep getting an error of undefined on output. Apologies I am sure it's something simple I missed, I am still learning all this.

The script:

```
function todayDateTime() {

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var todayDate = new Date();
var getCurrentHours = todayDate.getHours();
var getCurrentMinutes = todayDate.getMinutes();
var getCurrentAmPm = getCurrentHours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
var getTodayMonth =  todayDate.getMonth()+1;
var getTodayDate = todayDate.getDate();

var addSuffix = getTodayDate.dateSuffix;

var getTodayFullYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
getCurrentHours = getCurrentHours % 12;
getCurrentHours = getCurrentHours ? getCurrentHours : 12; 
getCurrentMinutes = getCurrentMinutes < 10 ? '0'+getCurrentMinutes : 
getCurrentMinutes;

var getCurrentDateTime = getCurrentHours + ':' + getCurrentMinutes + ' ' + 
getCurrentAmPm + '<br />' + monthNames[getTodayMonth] + ' ' + getTodayDate + 
addSuffix + ' ' + getTodayFullYear;


return(getCurrentDateTime);
}



function dateSuffix(i) {
var j = i % 10,
    k = i % 100;
if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
    return i + "st";
}
if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
    return i + "nd";
}
if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
    return i + "rd";
}
return i + "th";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little error in your code

```
var addSuffix = getTodayDate.dateSuffix;
```

Here you're trying to call the function/property .**dateSuffix** on the object **getTodayDate**.

getTodayDate is actually a variable holding the day as an integer. dateSuffix on the other hand is a function that expects a parameter in parantheses.

So simply change it to this:

```
var addSuffix = dateSuffix(getTodayDate);
```

Also, the following function already returns the day as a number

```
var getCurrentDateTime = getCurrentHours + ':' + getCurrentMinutes + ' ' + 
getCurrentAmPm + '<br />' + monthNames[getTodayMonth] + ' ' + getTodayDate + 
addSuffix + ' ' + getTodayFullYear;
```

So you don't need to return it from the dateSuffix function.

Change

```
return i + "th";
```

to

```
return  "th";
```

Here's a working example:

```js
function todayDateTime() {

  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  var todayDate = new Date();
  var getCurrentHours = todayDate.getHours();
  var getCurrentMinutes = todayDate.getMinutes();
  var getCurrentAmPm = getCurrentHours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  var getTodayMonth = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var getTodayDate = todayDate.getDate();
  var addSuffix = dateSuffix(getTodayDate);

  var getTodayFullYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
  getCurrentHours = getCurrentHours % 12;
  getCurrentHours = getCurrentHours ? getCurrentHours : 12;
  getCurrentMinutes = getCurrentMinutes < 10 ? '0' + getCurrentMinutes :
    getCurrentMinutes;

  var getCurrentDateTime = getCurrentHours + ':' + getCurrentMinutes + ' ' +
    getCurrentAmPm + '<br />' + monthNames[getTodayMonth] + ' ' + getTodayDate +
    addSuffix + ' ' + getTodayFullYear;


  return (getCurrentDateTime);
}



function dateSuffix(i) {
  var j = i % 10,
    k = i % 100;
  if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
    return "st";
  }
  if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
    return "nd";
  }
  if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
    return "rd";
  }
  return "th";
}

console.log(todayDateTime());
```

Comment: Dude, that's awesome, Thanks!, one little problem, it's now showing the suffix, although now It's saying it's July 33rd. I don't know where it picked up the extra 3 from.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, I realized it after I've posted the answer. I've updated it!

Comment: I made the change recommended, but I am still getting an output of 33rd. I did notice I was returning August, so corrected the month +1 to +0 which now returns July. Is there something else I'm missing for the extra 3 in there?

Comment: Maybe there's a little error elsewhere. I've added a working code snippet to my answer so you can see it in action.

Comment: I see that,, and yeah, your snippet is also returning the 33rd. It's so close, I am trying to spot the cause.

Comment: Outch sorry! I didn't see you've multiple return statements in there. You need to remove `i +` from each one!

Comment: No problem Ty H - glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Just use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

```js
console.log(moment('2019-07-04').format('MMMM do'));
console.log(moment('2019-07-03').format('MMMM do'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but I am trying to make the page work offline and not need to reference any other source if possible. I feel like I am pretty close with my script, but just missing something.